# Header file is not being read?

Tags: c++, header-files

So here is my code:

Main

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Tclass.h"
#include "Tclass.cpp"


using namespace std;


int main(){
    int x = 7;
    Tclass object;
    cout << object.OFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Header file

```
#ifndef TCLASS_H
#define TCLASS_H



class Tclass
{
    public:
        Tclass();
        int OFunction();
};

#endif // TCLASS_H
```

C++ style sheet(i believe that is what it is called)

```
#include "Tclass.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

Tclass::Tclass()
{
    cout << "An object for this class has been created \n";
}

int Tclass::OFunction(){
    srand(time(0));
    return 1+(rand()%6);
}
```

My issue is that i heard that i didn't need to include the `#include"Tclass.cpp"` in my code but without it my code won't run. Also i remove the the header file from the main it still works. I trust this person to be correct but i simply can not get this to work. The IDE i am using is code::blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to include the cpp file (and it's not called a style sheet, it's a source file) You compile main.cpp and Tclass.cpp separately into object files and then link the object file into one binary.

Oh and don't use `using namespace std`, don't copy code from text books, code in text books is very different from actual production code, code in text books is meant to be terse and only show the specific topic at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you should not include the .cpp files in your main program. Instead, you should ADD the file to the project (I haven't used Code::Blocks for a long time, but I'm sure there is a pretty obvious "Add file to project" option somewhere in the menus - either "File" or "Project" would be the first places to look).

[And no, it's called "Source file" - a style sheet is something you use in web-development]